# Should hot water be added to the already hot cooked vegetables for making a curry or even room temperature/cool water would do?

Tags: curry, stews

Does it change the taste, the texture, or anything else?

And no, I am not referring to potatoes or anything specific. I am talking about vegetables in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my personal experience. It takes sometime to reach the boiling temperature (again) when you add colder water. As a  result, vegetables get cooked for a longer period than anticipated.  This makes some vegetables becoming mushy and not tasting as good as otherwise. (Example: Egg Plant)  Therefore, I make sure to add the right amount of water in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no difference to the taste or texture that I've ever noticed. It does, however, slow the process down a bit as you have to bring the water back up to a simmer from cold.

Comment: I moved the comment to an answer.